# Difference between stock UIColor and custom UIColor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicolor

I'm trying to get RGB values from a UIColor object.

If I do the following on a UIColor object it works

```
UIColor *top = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
const CGFloat* colorsTop = 0;
colorsTop = CGColorGetComponents(top.CGColor);
```

Top comes out as: UICachedDeviceRGBColor *  0x7a7d5b50

However, if I do the following it fails. Can someone please explain why?

```
UIColor *top = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
const CGFloat* colorsTop = 0;
colorsTop = CGColorGetComponents(top.CGColor);
```

Top comes out as: UIColor * 0x7a7d5cb0

I'm getting error on the last one: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, 0xb7a7d5b9)

Comment: how does it fail - what happens ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does your phone explode? What is the error message?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do here? Seems like you're trying to get the RGB values out of the colour?

Comment: Yes, I'm after the RGB colors

Comment: See my answer. You are using the wrong method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the RGB components of a `UIColor` you should be using this method...

```
- (BOOL)getRed:(CGFloat *)red green:(CGFloat *)green blue:(CGFloat *)blue alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
```

Like this...

```
CGFloat red = 0;
CGFloat green = 0;
CGFloat blue = 0;
CGFloat alpha = 0;

[someUIColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
```

`red`, `green`, `blue`, and `alpha` will now contain the values of that colour.